# Corona SDK Using nativ text field in storyboard

Tags: sdk, textbox, lua, storyboard, coronasdk

So, I have a program that is using the corona storyboard.
There is scene 1 where the user can type something in a textbox at and there is also another scene, scene 2 where I have some text. The problem is that when the user goes away from the scene with the textbox, the textbox still appears on the screen. I've tried using removeSelf() which does delete it. But the problem is that the textbox is gone forever if i use removeSelf(), even when the user goes back to scene 1, it's still gone!
How could I fix this? Here is the code for scene 1:

---

```
--
-- view1.lua
--
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

function scene:createScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    local bg = display.newRect( 0, 0, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
    bg:setFillColor(0,255,0 )   -- green

    local title = display.newText( "Second View", 0, 0, native.systemFont, 32 )
    title:setTextColor( 0 ) -- black
    title:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
    title.x = display.contentWidth * 0.5
    title.y = 125

    local summary = display.newText( "Loaded by the first tab 'onPress' listener\n— specified in the 'tabButtons' table.", 0, 0, 300, 300, native.systemFont, 14 )
    summary:setTextColor( 0 ) -- black
    summary:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
    summary.x = display.contentWidth * 0.5 + 10
    summary.y = title.y + 215


    local function textListener( event )

    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then

        -- user begins editing text field
        print( event.text )

    elseif ( event.phase == "ended" ) then

        -- text field loses focus

    elseif ( event.phase == "ended" or event.phase == "submitted" ) then

        -- do something with defaulField's text

    elseif ( event.phase == "editing" ) then

        print( event.newCharacters )
        print( event.oldText )
        print( event.startPosition )
        print( event.text )

    end
end

-- Create our Text Field
defaultField = native.newTextField( 150, 150, 180, 30 )
defaultField:addEventListener( "userInput", textListener )
    -- all objects must be added to group (e.g. self.view)
    group:insert( bg )
    group:insert( title )
    group:insert( summary )
end

-- Called immediately after scene has moved onscreen:
function scene:enterScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    -- do nothing

end

-- Called when scene is about to move offscreen:
function scene:exitScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    -- INSERT code here (e.g. stop timers, remove listenets, unload sounds, etc.)

end

-- If scene's view is removed, scene:destroyScene() will be called just prior to:
function scene:destroyScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    -- INSERT code here (e.g. remove listeners, remove widgets, save state variables, etc.)

end

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- END OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- "createScene" event is dispatched if scene's view does not exist
scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )

-- "enterScene" event is dispatched whenever scene transition has finished
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )

-- "exitScene" event is dispatched whenever before next scene's transition begins
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )

-- "destroyScene" event is dispatched before view is unloaded, which can be
-- automatically unloaded in low memory situations, or explicitly via a call to
-- storyboard.purgeScene() or storyboard.removeScene().
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

Answer (score 0):

So maybe you could use alpha to hide all elements in group?

```
group.alpha=0
```

Comment: So I tried to put defaultField.alpha=0 in the scene:destroy() function, it worked (even tho the text box is still clickable) and also it won't go back to defaultField.alpha=1 when I go from scene 2 to scene 1. Gah!

Comment: so you place defaultField.alpha=0 in destroy() and defaultField.alpha=1 in enterScene() ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I did, and still stays alpha=0. (alpha doesn't seem optimal however, since the textfield is still clickable.)

Comment: place print("enter") within scene:enterScene and check if it goes there after entering scene. if not, you have to find why the event is not dispatched on enterScene

Comment: Interesting, it only prints "enter" the first time I goes to the scene! Wow. Will try to fix it! Thanks for your help!

EDIT: Maybe it's because I put it in the createScene and not enterScene? Think it works now!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the text box on the scene:enterScene method and remove it on the scene:exitScene.

Corona calls createScene only once, when creating the scene, but it calls enterScene and exitScene when the scene moves in or out of the stack. These are the places to create/remove elements.

For more information about screen management in corona you can read [this](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/04/02/cleaning-up-display-objects-andlisteners/). It's main focus is about cleaning up resources used in a scene and the examples are about sounds, but it applies to what you're trying to do and explains a little the Scene Management in Corona.